# Why is OpenCL memory allocation so slow on (some) of my NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Recently, after rebooting the GPU compute nodes at our lab, the cost of allocating memory through the OpenCL API (with `clCreateBuffer()`) seems to have gone through the roof.  I previously observed that allocation time was almost invariant to the number of bytes allocated, but all of a sudden there seems to be a strong correlation.  For example, using the benchmark program at http://lpaste.net/raw/356490, I *used* to get the following results on an NVIDIA K40 GPU:

`1 bytes; average: 382us; min: 364us; max: 501us
2 bytes; average: 376us; min: 364us; max: 478us
4 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 474us
8 bytes; average: 375us; min: 364us; max: 405us
16 bytes; average: 373us; min: 364us; max: 407us
32 bytes; average: 375us; min: 365us; max: 404us
64 bytes; average: 375us; min: 364us; max: 585us
128 bytes; average: 376us; min: 367us; max: 396us
256 bytes; average: 376us; min: 364us; max: 395us
512 bytes; average: 373us; min: 364us; max: 425us
1024 bytes; average: 371us; min: 365us; max: 421us
2048 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 472us
4096 bytes; average: 372us; min: 365us; max: 411us
8192 bytes; average: 371us; min: 364us; max: 394us
16384 bytes; average: 371us; min: 364us; max: 403us
32768 bytes; average: 374us; min: 365us; max: 554us
65536 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 407us
131072 bytes; average: 371us; min: 365us; max: 393us
262144 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 394us
524288 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 405us
1048576 bytes; average: 373us; min: 364us; max: 482us
2097152 bytes; average: 371us; min: 364us; max: 391us
4194304 bytes; average: 371us; min: 364us; max: 393us
8388608 bytes; average: 380us; min: 363us; max: 487us
16777216 bytes; average: 372us; min: 364us; max: 474us
33554432 bytes; average: 371us; min: 365us; max: 391us
67108864 bytes; average: 373us; min: 349us; max: 593us
134217728 bytes; average: 372us; min: 365us; max: 399us
268435456 bytes; average: 372us; min: 365us; max: 410us
536870912 bytes; average: 376us; min: 364us; max: 473us`

But now, using the same GPU and same CUDA version (8.0), I get the following results:

`1 bytes; average: 136us; min: 127us; max: 367us
2 bytes; average: 133us; min: 127us; max: 147us
4 bytes; average: 134us; min: 128us; max: 155us
8 bytes; average: 133us; min: 128us; max: 153us
16 bytes; average: 133us; min: 128us; max: 149us
32 bytes; average: 132us; min: 128us; max: 145us
64 bytes; average: 133us; min: 128us; max: 153us
128 bytes; average: 143us; min: 132us; max: 371us
256 bytes; average: 138us; min: 133us; max: 170us
512 bytes; average: 138us; min: 133us; max: 157us
1024 bytes; average: 140us; min: 133us; max: 164us
2048 bytes; average: 141us; min: 133us; max: 273us
4096 bytes; average: 138us; min: 133us; max: 158us
8192 bytes; average: 138us; min: 132us; max: 155us
16384 bytes; average: 139us; min: 132us; max: 178us
32768 bytes; average: 139us; min: 133us; max: 156us
65536 bytes; average: 139us; min: 133us; max: 173us
131072 bytes; average: 138us; min: 132us; max: 157us
262144 bytes; average: 138us; min: 127us; max: 442us
524288 bytes; average: 134us; min: 127us; max: 279us
1048576 bytes; average: 134us; min: 127us; max: 264us
2097152 bytes; average: 227us; min: 144us; max: 239us
4194304 bytes; average: 424us; min: 214us; max: 436us
8388608 bytes; average: 819us; min: 409us; max: 849us
16777216 bytes; average: 1606us; min: 815us; max: 1625us
33554432 bytes; average: 3181us; min: 1610us; max: 3211us
67108864 bytes; average: 6377us; min: 3239us; max: 6423us
134217728 bytes; average: 12693us; min: 6421us; max: 12772us
268435456 bytes; average: 25333us; min: 12789us; max: 25593us
536870912 bytes; average: 50606us; min: 25512us; max: 50975us`

I get similar behaviour on other GPUs in our lab (GTX 780Tis and a Titan Black), all of which also have RHEL 7.4 and CUDA 8.  I would be OK with some kind of relationship between allocation size and time, but these times also seem quite ridiculous.  50ms for allocating 500MiB?  I have a home machine running Fedora 26 and CUDA 8 with an NVIDIA GTX 770, where I get the following results:

`1 bytes; average: 269us; min: 156us; max: 574us
2 bytes; average: 286us; min: 140us; max: 510us
4 bytes; average: 271us; min: 156us; max: 595us
8 bytes; average: 272us; min: 163us; max: 563us
16 bytes; average: 171us; min: 152us; max: 325us
32 bytes; average: 178us; min: 148us; max: 301us
64 bytes; average: 171us; min: 156us; max: 387us
128 bytes; average: 171us; min: 150us; max: 315us
256 bytes; average: 163us; min: 150us; max: 470us
512 bytes; average: 175us; min: 148us; max: 350us
1024 bytes; average: 173us; min: 155us; max: 471us
2048 bytes; average: 172us; min: 151us; max: 286us
4096 bytes; average: 177us; min: 148us; max: 401us
8192 bytes; average: 188us; min: 156us; max: 527us
16384 bytes; average: 177us; min: 147us; max: 407us
32768 bytes; average: 167us; min: 151us; max: 506us
65536 bytes; average: 174us; min: 145us; max: 294us
131072 bytes; average: 166us; min: 150us; max: 406us
262144 bytes; average: 173us; min: 163us; max: 276us
524288 bytes; average: 172us; min: 152us; max: 431us
1048576 bytes; average: 180us; min: 150us; max: 423us
2097152 bytes; average: 170us; min: 150us; max: 391us
4194304 bytes; average: 171us; min: 162us; max: 238us
8388608 bytes; average: 182us; min: 157us; max: 420us
16777216 bytes; average: 167us; min: 159us; max: 225us
33554432 bytes; average: 188us; min: 164us; max: 539us
67108864 bytes; average: 200us; min: 180us; max: 403us
134217728 bytes; average: 269us; min: 234us; max: 478us
268435456 bytes; average: 333us; min: 300us; max: 610us
536870912 bytes; average: 495us; min: 455us; max: 719us`

This seems much more reasonable to me.  The change in behaviour did not coincide with any software updates that I am aware of, but did coincide with all the machines being rebooted.  One perhaps important difference is that my home machine runs kernel version 4.12, while the slow machines at the lab run 3.10.

**edit**: my home machine (which is still fast) runs version 375.66 of the `nvidia` driver, while the lab machines run 384.66.

Comment: Assuming you are using 64-bits process, do you reset the GPU between tests ? Also, could you produce a sample code ?

Comment: There is a link to the test program in my question.  The GPU is not reset between tests.

Comment: It could be related to your graphics driver or X.. What are the versions in the  2 cases?

Comment: I am using version 375.66 and 384.66 of the kernel driver.  There is no graphics or X driver - these are headless machines.